# Missing http header in Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-headers

I'm having an issue with some missing http headers in a Ajax response. The ajax-page (.NET) adds som additional info to the http header by using Me.Response.AddHeader("ResponseCode", mResponseCode). If I access the ajax-page directly and use httpAnalyser to check the headers, I can see that the headers are added correctly. But when I call the Ajax page through jQuery, the headers are missing.

I'm puzzled. Anyone out there that can help me?

Best regards, 
Steffen

Answer (score 1):

In your complete or success method the first parameter is an `XMLHttpRequest` object that contains this information. You can retrieve any response header like this:

```
xmlHttpRequest.getResponseHeader('header-name');
```

Comment: Yes - I know. But when I try that I get an empty string, because the header that I'm accessing is not present in the http header when I call the page through Ajax. It is however present if I access the Ajax page directly.

Comment: You can also check the headers for AJAX calls with Firefox's Firebug add-in (using the Net tab). So you know if the header is really missing and if the problem is on the server or on the client.

Comment: The headers was not present, but it turned out that is was a problem elsewhere which cause the problem. 

But thanks for trying to help me out :-)